# Multiple OR conditions in WHERE clause - return only one record

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

I have a query where records are selected for each user based on 4 conditions. I want to return only one of these records for each user based on a heirachy - for example: if the first criteria is met (e.g. `gemid = 123`), don't include any more records for that user.

**UPDATE** as per Op De Cirkel's comment, I am wanting to exclude multiple `subscribe, userid` pairs

Query:

```
SELECT subscribeid, userid
FROM subscribe 
WHERE (gemid=123) OR
      (grade=1 AND page IS NULL AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) OR
      (grade=1 AND page ="page1" AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) OR
      (grade=1 AND page ="page1" AND page2 = "page2" AND gemid IS NULL )
```

Comment: try using `DISTINCT`, and check with `EXPLAIN` if it is better optimized. (It should be)

Comment: Your "I want to short circuit the `OR`" is different then the actual question: The `OR` in the `where` clause **IT IS** short-circuited. What you want is excluding multiple `(subscribeid, userid)` pairs in the result which is a different thing. And if you don't have indexes on the columns used in the `where` clause, the engine has to go through all the records because it can not know if the next row satisfies the condition before checking it

Comment: You are of course correct regarding wanting to exclude multiple `subscribe, userid` pairs. That clarification helps a lot. I will remove the 'short circuit' from the post and title as it is incorrect. There are indexes on the columns. I am close to a solution using a `WHEN` clause and will post.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - I'm curious what your take is on my posted answer as a solution. It's all I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could figure out was to calculate which part of the `WHERE` statement met the criteria and include it with the result set as the field `level` - and sort by `userid, level`. I can then take the first record for each user in the result set. I couldn't figure out how to only include this one record for each user without creating a temporary table.

In reality, this isn't any solution since I could process this in php as well.

```
SELECT gemid, grade, page, page2, subscribeid, userid,
    CASE WHEN (gemid=123) THEN 1 ELSE
      CASE 
      WHEN (grade='1' AND page IS NULL AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) THEN 2
          ELSE
              CASE 
              WHEN (grade='1' AND page ="page1" AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) THEN 3 
              ELSE
                  CASE 
                  WHEN (grade='1' AND page ="page1" AND page2 = "page2" AND gemid IS NULL ) THEN 4 
                  ELSE
                      null
                  END
              END
          END
      END level
    FROM subscribe s
    WHERE (gemid=123) OR
          (grade='1' AND page IS NULL AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) OR
          (grade='1' AND page ="page1" AND page2 IS NULL AND gemid IS NULL ) OR
          (grade='1' AND page ="page1" AND page2 = "page2" AND gemid IS NULL )
    ORDER BY userid, level
```